# Delete old data rows in sheet using google forms

Tags: google-apps-script

I want the sheet that collects data from a google form to delete old data.  I have this script in the sheet but it doesn't seem to run when new data is added via the form.

```
function onEdit(e) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("1054");
var datarange = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastrow = datarange.getLastRow();
var values = datarange.getValues();// get all data in a 2D array

var currentDate = new Date();
var oneweekago = new Date();
oneweekago.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 7);

for (i=lastrow;i>=2;i--) {
var tempdate = values[i-1][0];

if(tempdate < oneweekago)  
{
  sheet.deleteRow(i);
}
```

The sheet it is linked to is called 1054.

Do I need to put appscript in the Form?  If so, what would that be?

Comment: You must "install" and "On Form Submit" trigger.  Rename `onEdit(e)` to something else.  `onEdit()` is a "reserved" function name.  You should not use a reserved function name for the "On Form Submit" trigger.  Give it your own unique name.  Then from the code editor, click the "Edit" menu and "Current projects triggers" and add a trigger.

Comment: So I need to put a script on the form that will run the script in the sheet?  How do I do that?

Comment: An "On Form Submit" trigger can be added to a Form a spreadsheet or both.  It's easier to add the "On Form Submit" trigger to a spreadsheet.  It's easier to get the data, and if you want the code to affect the spreadsheet, then it's a more direct relationship.  From the code editor, choose "Help" and then "Documentation"  Search the words "event object"

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to leave the sheet and the form it is attached to alone. Here's what I do on a form that's on my website.

```
function formSubmitEvent(e) 
{
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById('SpreadsheetID');
    var sht=ss.getSheetByName('ResponseReview');//this is another sheet I used for reviewing the responses.
    sht.appendRow(e.values);//I append a row to the ResponseReview sheet
    selfEmail(e.values);//and I send myself an email if my quota is above 75
}
```

Even if you delete old data on the linked sheet the form will continue adding data where it left off because evidently it keeps track of what the next row is.

In general, I leave the linked sheet alone.  It is true that I built my form in Googgle Apps Script so at some point when I get a lot of responses then I will unlink the form and delete both and rebuild the form by running that script and a new form and sheet will be linked but I will continue my review process in the other sheet which also has the capability to create a Google Doc from the submitted data.  In essence, it doesn't really matter to me where the form wants to put the data because I capture the onFormSubmit trigger and I put into my ResponseReview sheet from the values array.  And I can do anything I want with that sheet without affecting the linkage.